# Under what condition sum of the norm squared is less than of square of the norm of average

Tags: inequality, average, sums-of-squares

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be some given vectors such that $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \neq 0$. Is there a constant $c>0$ such that the following holds?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\| x_i\|^2 \leq c\|\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\|^2
$$
If so, what that $c$ would be?

Comment: No. The RHS may be arbitrarily small, with no incidence on the LHS.

Comment: If $\sum x_i=0,$ you kind of have a problem.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I have excluded that case in the statement. Am I right?

Comment: Sure, I missed that. But excluding that doesn't do you much good by continuity of both sides in the $x_i.$ For example, with $x_2=-x_1$ and $\|x_3\|$ small, and all other $x_i=0,$ you get $2\|x_1\|^2+\|x_3\|\leq c\|x_3\|$ for all $x_3.$ @Sepide

Comment: Basically, for continuous function $f:\mathbb R^M\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(z)\geq 0$ for all $x$ in some dense subset of $\mathbb R^M,$ then the inequality is true on all of $\mathbb R^M.$ In your case, $M=n\times N,$ and $f(x_1,\dots,x_N)=c\|\sum x_i\|^2-\sum\|x_i\|^2.$

Comment: I missed the squares in my prior comment starting with "Sure, I missed that..." but the idea works if you correct it. Should have been: $2\|x_1\|^2+\|x_3\|^2\leq c\|x_3\|^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the claim is false. Take for example
$$x_1=e_1, \hspace{10pt} x_2=(-1+\frac{1}{k})e_1$$
for $k$ arbitrarily great (and $x_h=0$ for every $h \geq 3$).